# Does Trials of the Blood Dragon have a track editor?

Tags: trials-of-the-bd

Trials HD, Evolution and Fusion have a track editor and tracks can be shared online in the two latter games. Since the game can be described as a spin-off (around half of the tracks are 2D platforming sections - on foot) is a track editor included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Sources:

[PC Gamer review](http://www.pcgamer.com/trials-of-the-blood-dragon-review/)
[IGN review](http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/06/17/trials-of-the-blood-dragon-review)